# Can I create dynamic lists within Ansible vars_files?

Tags: file, variables, ansible

I have a variables file that includes important info about our databases; the server they are on, the db version, the DB_HOME directory, etc. In the variables file, I would like to dynamically create lists that capture the unique values of those properties, so they can be easily iterated through in a task.

I have equivalent functionality by creating the list on the fly in a task's *loop* option, but that means repeating that loop syntax (violates DRY principle) and I would like less sophisticated Ansible colleagues to be able to use a pre-defined list.

example of the variables file databases.yml:

```
databases:
- name: test_db1
  server: ora_901
  listener: LISTENER_XYZ
  version: '11.2.0.4'
  oracle_home: '/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_home'

- name: test_db2
  server: ora_902
  listener: LISTENER_ABC
  version: '11.2.0.4'
  oracle_home: '/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_home'

## This didn't work... was hoping I could build this list dynamically
listeners:
- name: "{{ item }}"
  loop:  "{{ databases | map(attribute = 'listener') | list | unique }}"

servers:
- name: "{{ item }}"
  loop:  "{{ databases | map(attribute = 'server') | list | unique }}"
```

I would then use this loop through either the 'listeners' or 'servers' lists directly with some tasks.

When I tried a task that referenced the listeners variable, it failed. Referencing databases works and all items are returned, so I know it's getting some data from the vars_file...

```
- vars_files:
    - vars/databases.yml
  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: "{{ databases }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ listeners }}"

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [FQDN] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "listener": "LISTENER_XYZ",
            "name": "test_db1",
            "oracle_home": "/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_home",
            "server": "ora_901",
            "version": "11.2.0.4"
        },
        {
            "listener": "LISTENER_ABC",
            "name": "test_db2",
            "oracle_home": "/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1",
            "server": "ora_902",
            "version": "11.2.0.4"
        },

fatal: [FQDN]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/xxx/test_vars.yml': line 21, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"}
```

I would really like to keep these dynamic definitions in the same place as the server definitions, and don't see why it wouldn't be possible, I'm just sure I'm using the wrong mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from Ansible doc// Just to give you an idea, about "[loop_control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)".

You can nest two looping tasks using include_tasks. However, by default Ansible sets the loop variable item for each loop. This means the inner, nested loop will overwrite the value of item from the outer loop. You can specify the name of the variable for each loop using loop_var with loop_control:

```
# main.yml
- include_tasks: inner.yml
  loop:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item

# inner.yml
- debug:
    msg: "outer item={{ outer_item }} inner item={{ item }}"
  loop:
    - a
    - b
    - c
```